What does "for good" mean in this context?
I read the lyrics from Cover Me Up by Jason Isbell

It's cold in this house and I ain't going out to chop wood
So cover me up and know you're enough
To use me for good

It is not clear to me what "to use me for good" should mean here.

It's a song, it doesn't have to 'mean' anything. We don't even know if the singer or writer are native speakers.

@MichaelHarvey I would like to know what a (native) speaker of American English would understand by the line "to use me for good". Is this like "to use me forever"? Or something "to use me for a good purpose"? Or something else?

You got it. "To use me forever" or "to use me for a good purpose" or "something else". One of those three for sure. It's a song.

The infinitival clause "to use me for good" would be a complement of the adjective enough  Compare: "Do we have enough gas in the car? -- Yes, it is enough to get us there".  But "you're enough to use me for good" makes no sense.  Struggling to make sense of the line, "enough" could mean "up to the challenge", and in that case "for good" would be "for some good end or purpose".  The alternative meaning of "for good" is "forever".   "He lost the last election but is back again. We haven't gotten rid of him for good".  But "enough to use me forever" makes no sense.

MichaelHarvey is a speaker of British English and I'm a speaker of American English but I don't think there's anything peculiar to American English that would shed further light on this.

Here is the complete lyrics, also see What Is “Cover Me Up” About? ... ultimately depicts a wonderful night alone with that special someone, while also delving into all the wasted nights it took to get there.

@TimR - arguably 'enough' is there to rhyme with 'me up' rather than actually, like, mean anything, and likewise 'good' and 'wood'. Words of songs are very often written long after the tune, and they have to fit that.

@MichaelHarvey You're probably right. There's another verse where the preceding line is "Like a piece of driftwood".

It's hard for me decide what reason to give for my close vote. 1) One requirement of questions about meanings is that you look them up in a dictionary and tell about the questions remaining afterward. A dictionary won't resolve the potential ambiguity for you, but it would be a start, and if it's unclear, then an answer addressing that unclearness will be more useful. 2) "For good" can mean either "forever" or "for good purposes." While the latter is perhaps more likely, there isn't enough context here to tell, so a close reason of "needs details or clarity" is also an option. ...

... 3) Poetry is often intentionally unclear and open to multiple interpretations, nor must it always even have a meaning that is readily apparent ("Shining flying purple wolfhound show me where you are"?). It's entirely possible that even with full context this line could be intentionally ambiguous, so "what do you make of it" becomes an opinion-based question, and literary interpretation is off-topic here.

@MichaelHarvey  I purposely don't stray into "aesthetic" explanations  like that and try to confine my answers to syntax and the literal meaning or standard (non-idiosyncratic) figurative usages. I just say whether the poem or lyrics do or don't make coherent sense in the same way we'd make that judgment about a piece of prose excerpted from the instruction booklet for a toaster.

It is also ok to answer that the line of the song is ambiguous. I am not a native speaker of English, and so it was not clear to me that this line may indeed have several meanings at once.

But 'several meanings at once' are exactly what one expects from song lyrics and poetry, surely? https://www.kencraftauthor.com/the-fraught-question-of-a-poems-meaning

@MichaelHarvey I am sorry to cause misunderstandings. I am aware that poetry can use words ambiguously on purpose, but I started this question with the assumption that the ambiguity I am seeing in that particular line is not a "real" ambiguity, but just my lack of understanding of the English language. If this is not the case, and my assumption was wrong, this is also a valid answer to my question.

OP's query is on lyrics from the song "Cover me up" a song written and recorded by American singer-songwriter Jason Isbell.

"To use me for good".
It is not clear to me what "to use me for good" should mean here.

It is necessary to know the background of the songwriter to deeply understand the meaning of the lyrics.
I. The song and the singer's background..

Reference Wikipedia
Isbell wrote the song about his wife, Amanda Shires. He described the song as "a hard one for me to even get through without breaking down the first time" because of how personally he felt that it expressed his love for Shires.
The corresponding album came after Isbell had ended alcohol rehabilitation.
In 2020, Paste ranked the song number one on their list of the 20 greatest Jason Isbell songs, and in 2022, American Songwriter ranked the song number four on their list of the 10 greatest Jason Isbell songs.

II. Meaning of the lyrics:.
OP has guessed it correctly -  something "to use me for a good purpose.
Isbell is pointing out that he had given up the bad things (alcoholism).

Reference holler.country.
The phrasing of the titular line -
“Cover me up, and know you're enough / To use me for good” - has always felt somewhat strange, with Isbell giving his wife assurance that she can ‘use’ him for good.
The impetus behind the line, though, is Isbell simply highlighting to Amanda how he no longer lusts after anything, such as alcohol, and instead is entirely content being with her.
https://holler.country/news/general/cover-me-up-by-morgan-wallen-lyrics-and-meaning/


I've downvoted your answer because answers here about poetry and lyrics should be about the language not about the life struggles of the author.

@TimR If the question is off topic, it should be closed. The answer is designed according to the question.

I would disagree. There's no need to adduce alcohol rehab to explain the syntax and possible meanings of "you're enough to use me for good". No need to mention names. No need to give the song's ranking.  No need for any of the stuff you've written and cited.

Excellent answer, thank you.

@JFabianMeier When I searched for the answer, I realised that the songwriter poured his heart and soul into this song, drawing from his own personal experiences. +1
